# Проблема с bat скриптом

Tags: cmd, bat

Есть маленький bat файл:

```
@echo off
chcp 1251

TITLE = [SERVER NAME]

:runserver
echo some java process running
rem Здесь работает некое java приложение.
echo some java process stopped

:action
echo Что делаем дальше?
echo run = Запускаем сервер;
echo exit = Закрываем консоль.
SET /P ACTION=Ваш выбор:
echo %ACTION%

if "%ACTION%"=="" {
   echo Введён неизвестный аргумент!
   goto :action
}

if "%ACTION%"=="run" {
   echo Запускаю сервер [SERVER NAME].
   goto :runserver
}

if "%ACTION%"=="exit" {
   echo Работа окончена.
   PAUSE
   exit
}

goto :runserver
```

Хотел сделать удобный "запускатор" с ветвлением. Проблема в том, что строка `if "%ACTION%"==""`всегда `true`. Чтобы я не вводил.

Comment: `cmd` **не** использует `{` и `}` для выделения блока команд.

Comment: Чёт реально затупил, сейчас проверю.

Comment: Проблема решена! Поменял на `(` и `)` и всё работает. Спасибо!